Zero argument constructor Error in the Receiver Class
I am writing an app that will implement scheduled alarms which has problem in the Receiver Class.
What I want is, firstly, an alarm will be implemented in onCreate Part in the MainActivity.
Then at specific time, when the onRecive void receives the pendingIntent, the onReceive void will call another void in MainActivity. This is done by creating an interface and with empty void so that onReceive can call the method of the same name in MainActivity.
Finally the onReceive void will decide whether a notification shall be sent out depending on the result of the void called from MainActivity through interface.
I tried to referring to this answer and modify it to my script but it returns an error of
Process: com.example.sahelper, PID: 5930
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.example.sahelper.alarm.AlarmReceiver: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.example.sahelper.alarm.AlarmReceiver> has no zero argument constructor


Here is my MainActivity
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // AlarmController is used to schedule alarm
        AlarmController alarmController = 
            new AlarmController(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.this); 
        alarmController.new_test_alarm(); // schedule an alarm
    }

    // This method is supposed to be called by interface
    @Override
    public void check_duty()
    {
        // Do something here...
        // Do something here...
        // Do something here...
    }

Here is my AlarmController.java
    // Constructor
    public AlarmController(Activity activity, Context context)
    {
        this.myactivity = activity;
        this.mycontext = context;
    }

    public void new_test_alarm()
    {
        // Some codes here...
        // Some codes here...
        // Some codes here...

        Intent intent = new Intent(myactivity, AlarmReceiver.class);
        intent.setAction(SECOND_DEADLINE_ALARM_RECEIVE_ACTION);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                                    mycontext,
                                    Integer.parseInt(it.getKey()), // Here is the noti_id
                                    intent,
                                    FLAG_MUTABLE);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) myactivity.getSystemService   
                                (Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                                    (System.currentTimeMillis() + 10 * 1000),
                                    pendingIntent);
}

Here is my interface
public interface Receiver_MainActivity_Interface
{
    public void check_duty();
}

And finally, here is my receiver class
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    private Receiver_MainActivity_Interface mylistener;
    public AlarmReceiver(Receiver_MainActivity_Interface listener)
    {
        this.mylistener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        if (Objects.equals(intent.getAction(), SECOND_DEADLINE_ALARM_RECEIVE_ACTION))
        {
            mylistener.check_duty();
            
            // And some codes here continue...
            // And some codes here continue...
            // And some codes here continue...
        }
    }
}

I supsect the problem comes from the "Intent intent = new Intent(myactivity, AlarmReceiver.class);" as parameter shall be passed to AlarmReceiver class. But how should I pass the interface as a variable to it when I define an intent?
What shall I do to fix the problem? Any suggestion is appreciated.
Edit
I cannot and do not think it is possible to move the void inside mainactivity to onReceive class because this void involves some elements declared (WebView) in MainActivity.

If your check_duty function is checking a UI element of your activity, your entire architecture is broken.  There is no reason to believe that your Activity will still exist by that time.  Broadcast Receivers are meant to launch even apps that have been completely exited, and Alarms frequently do that.  And even if it wasn't, your Activity would have been destroyed if the app was ever backgrounded for more than a few seconds.  In addition, the references required to give the Receiver access to the Activity would cause a memory leak.

Your receiver's constructor has a parameter:
public AlarmReceiver(Receiver_MainActivity_Interface listener)

But the framework can't provide the argument.
A pending intent can outlive your application's process, so by the time the receiver runs, the activity will not exist anymore. In other words, you can't rely on any state inside the Activity.
Another issue is that the receiver is expected to do all the work in the background, without any UI (other than a notification).
If you need to start an activity then you should be aware of the restrictions on starting activities from the background.
My suggestion in this case is to post a notification with another pending intent and let the user open an Activity from the notification.
